# Error connecting to a sqlserver R2 from java fx app

Tags: javafx

I have tried to use the code i provided below but it keeps giving me errors.

ERROR:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection string contains a badly formed name or value.

```
DBConnection Class

    public static Connection martConnection(){
        Connection con = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

            String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://SQLEXPRESS:49672;Management;integratedSecurity=true;";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return con; 
}
```

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection string contains a badly formed name or value.